# Creating a Repository Pattern Interface

Tags: generics, design-patterns, interface, repository

I'm new to using interfaces in C#. I was watching a tutorial about it and learned how to use it.

I'm really into best practices. On the tutorial, it only uses a Person class on the Interface to do CRUD. I'm just wondering if it's advisable to create different Interface Repositories for each model class e.g. Person (IPersonRepository), Animal (IAnimalRespository) etc or can I just use an IObjectRepository if the operations are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the operations are the same, you can go with a generic and generalized repository interface.

Once you need some specific method to cover a specific requirement, you create a less generalized interface in place.

You need to consider that as C# is a strongly-typed language, if you're building your solution using *dependency injection*, you'll need to replace the generic/generalized interface type wherever you've decided to define a concrete interface:

```
// This is a sample of what I was talking about in the previous paragraph. 
// Just imagine how many places might need to replace IRepository<Animal>
// with IAnimalRepository in a big solution!
public class WhateverService
{
     public WhateverService(IRepository<Animal> animalRepository)
     {
     }
}
```

The decision is up to you and it's based on the size of your project.

Comment: Thanks Matias. Is there a performance implication on using Generics?

Comment: @ReydanGatchalian I don't think so. Generics avoids casting in many situations and yours is one. Just imagine that your generalized repository would need to work with the base class of all your domain objects: you would need to downcast references to your concrete domain objects like `Animal` and many others. You avoid this with generics.

Comment: Thank you very much Matias.

Comment: @ReydanGatchalian No problem, you're welcome. If you like *repository pattern*, you might be interested on this alternate way of implementing it: http://designpattern.ninja/catalog/design-patterns/agnostic-repository